# Error while installing couch DB version 1.5.1

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, couchrest, couchdb-python

While installing couch DB 1.5.1 from source, in the step where `make` is called I get this error

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `THANKS', needed by `THANKS.gz'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/somedir'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Machine details

```
Linux machinename 2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 24 09:37:37 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I saw from Couch DB bug archives that this is a locale problem and setting

```
export LC_TYPE=C
```

Would solve the issue, but it doesn't solve the issue.

I followed the instructions from this URL for guidance, overcame a lot of obstacles before this, and eventually stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Link is `http://asaf.github.io/blog/2013/07/08/installing-couch-db-on-amazon-ami/`

Comment: I guess I found the issue. In the root directory, there is no THANKS file, the file name is THANKS.in. Changing it to THANKS.in in the Makefile.am file resolved the issue. Not sure what this means, but it solved the problem. Will dig further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THANKS file isn't available since it's generated automatically from git log - you'd probably downloaded git archive instead. To solve the issue:

1. use `git clone` to get the source code
2. OR just `touch THANKS` to workaround the issue in your case
3. OR use distributed sources from official [web site](http://couchdb.apache.org/#download)

Comment: Yup, found that out. Thanks for detailed explanation though. This could be useful to others who may hit the same issue.